# What does the term "veg*n" mean?

Tags: veganism, terminology

You sometimes see the term "veg*n" on sites such as this one. What exactly does this term mean? Why is it used?

Comment: I had guessed the answer when I first saw it thanks to my programmer background, but this is a very good question as today was the first time I have seen this term used.

Comment: We're trying to [avoid use of veg*n](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234/should-we-change-vegn-questions-to-vegan-vegetarian-for-search-engines) on this site now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Veg*n *(or Veg*an)* refers to both vegans and vegetarians. The use of the asterisk derives from its use in computer languages as a wildcard which can capture any sequence of characters.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/veg*n)