# How is the word "veg*n" used in oral communication?

Tags: culture

Recently I saw someone use the word

Veg*n

on this site and I had never seen it before. According to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/veg*n), it appears to be a term that includes both vegetarians and vegans. And indeed there is a [question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/661/what-does-the-term-vegn-mean) already on this site about its meaning. My question is, how does one pronounce this word? Is it strictly used only in written text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never heard anyone say this. People usually say 'vegetarian or vegan' to convey the same meaning. There is no verbal shortcut, as far as I know. A less precise workaround would be 'plant-based', as both diets are based on plants, with vegetarianism adding animal products on top of this basis. Another possibility might be 'veggie', as in 'She's a veggie', or 'It's a veggie dish'. This word is  ambiguous enough to cover both meanings, but unlike veg*n it doesn't also convey that this is intentional.

Comment: Yeah I think veg\*n is unpronounceable and I have certainly never heard anyone attempt to say it. For most people speaking is a lot less effort than typing/writing. Possibly relevant [Is there a difference between "vegan" and "plant-based"?](//vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/276) - I don't agree with you that plant-based can be used for vegetarian diets. If I hear plant-based I assume vegan (though I usually pedantically ask for clarification)

Comment: Good answer. Although, I agree with Zanna that if I hear plant-based I automatically assume vegan.